# Laravel get cache key using regex or like operator

Tags: laravel, redis

I want to get Laravel Redis cache key using regex or like key operator.

I have tried everything and spend lost of time but no luck with that can anyone please help on this.

```
$redis = Cache::getRedis();
$keys = $redis->keys("*$key_name*");
$count = 0;
$result = [];

foreach ($keys as $key) {
   $result[$key] = $redis->get($key);
}      
return $result;
```

I have tried above code but no luck. can any one help on this?

Comment: Could you please post some more information like what you're trying to accomplish, what you've tried, screenshots, and snippets of code.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You can implement something like

```
$redis = Cache::getRedis();
$keys = $redis->keys("*$key_name*");
$count = 0;
$result = [];

foreach ($keys as $key) {
    $result[$key] = $redis->get($key);
}      
return $result;
```